# Text SVG losing formatting and glyphs when export from illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, glyphs

I am exporting SVG from illustrator and the text with special characters is falling apart with special characters. Is there a way to do this correctly?

This is what it should look like

[image: screenshot of illustrator]

This is what the SVG looks like

[image: Screenshot of SVG]

Any Tips?

Comment: You are using a swash cap, which is an Open Type feature that `svg` likely won't support. Converting your type to oulines the way Wouter suggests, is your best option imho.

Comment: Thanks I knew this was a possibility but I wanted to keep it as text not an outline... thanks for confirming my fears though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the text might solve your problem.

1. Select the text
2. Choose **Object** > **Expand...**
3. Click Ok.

Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks I knew this was a possibility but I wanted to keep it as text not an outline... thanks for confirming my fears though

Comment: Any time--and keep in mind that I might be wrong. Welcome to GDSE!

Comment: I suspect you are correct